# Sending huge amount of data received from slow external web service via stream

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf

I wrote small REST web service using WCF. These web service will be serve as facade to other more specialized webservices.

So it look like:
Java App (client) <-> My Rest WCF Web Service <-> External_Web_Services

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/GetListOfRecordByRootId/{userid}/{rootId}")]
    List<RecordDTO> GetListOfRecordByRootId(string userid, string rootId);
```

But it work in this way:

```
public List<TimeSeriesDto> GetListOfTimeseriesByDataSetId(string guid, string dataSetId, string numberOfSeries)
{
    Var client = this.OpenToExternalWebservice();
    return client.GetDataByRootId.ToList();
}
```

Where OpenToExternalWebservice open connection to web service. But I meet one serious problem -> amount of data.
It turn out that external webservice are quite slow and limited. Alone result are huge. - I received more then 200MB of result.

Question: Is it possible to return data via stream at chuncked way?
Let’s present you small example:

DataAtRoot have 100 000 records;

Step 1) I download first 1000 records from external web service

Step 2)After receive it I convert them to: List. Then I will pack it to json usign DataContactJsonSerializer.

Step 3)After convert them to Json I wamt to send it via stream but I DONT want to close connection.

Step 4) Remove old 1000records which I sended.

Step 5) Back to step 1 (get next 1000records)

So my dream is sending many list of record via stream:

ONE STREAM where I will put after receiving next part of data:

```
List<Record> Row Number 0-999
List<Record> Row Number 1000-1999
List<Record> Row Number 2000-2999
List<Record> Row Number 3000-3999
```

…

Is it possible? Or maybe do you have another solution?

Comment: Depends on what data is coming over the wire? Is it XML. Json, txt, csv or something else? As far as I'm aware there is no simple way to do it but if you know the format it will arrive in, you can write a clever streaming service which buffers the received packets, listens for an "end of record" combination whether it's an XML closing tag or a line break. Takes whatever was accumulated and then forwards it on to the receiver while continuing to receive more packets from the sender.

Comment: Record have two field - sequency number and bool lastDTO. Last DTO will be set on true if some data will be the last one.

Comment: External web service is SOAP service. So I will receive it as XML. But I can ask for 1000 record only in one time (even if root have 2mln records). So request - 1000record, next request 1000 record. But java app will be asking me only once so I wonder if I can send many packages via one stream (without closing)

Comment: Just to clarify, the proxy service you're writing is in C# right?

Comment: Right, absolutely in C#.